# What does Tab(Col) mean in t-sql?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I needed to create a table from XML in Microsoft SQL Server Management 2008. The following creates the table that I need, however I do not know what Tab(Col) does. The table and xml are simplified for examples sake. Can someone please explain to me what Tab(Col) is doing? Thanks

**NOTE: This is working as it is. Just need a conceptual explanation.**

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<Root>
               <Order>
                  <customer_id> 1 </customer_id>
                  <credit> 1.03 </credit>
               </Order>
               <Order>                 
                  <customer_id> 2 </customer_id>
                  <credit> 1500585412.02 </credit>
               </Order>
               <Order>
                  <customer_id> 3 </customer_id>
                  <credit> 10.25 </credit>
               </Order>
            <Root>'

SELECT tab.col.value('customer_id[1]','INT') as customer_id,
       tab.col.value('credit[1]','MONEY') as credit
INTO #temp_order
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Order') Tab(Col)

SELECT * FROM #temp_order
```

This will create the table #temp_order:

```
customer_id  | credit
             |
          1  | 1.03 
          2  | 1500585412.02 
          3  | 10.25
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sql"? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: My apologies. It's in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `FROM` statement, `Tab(Col)` specifies [table and column aliases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) for the results of `@xml.nodes('/Root/Order')`:

```
[ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]
<table_source> ::= 
{
    # ...
    | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] ) [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
}
```

This names them so they can be referred to as a table, `Tab`, with 1 column, `Col`.

```sql
SELECT tab.col.value(-- ...
--     ^^^ ^^^
```

It could also be written with an optional `AS` keyword:

```
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Order') AS Tab(Col)
```

Comment: +1 - the call to `.nodes()` returns a *list* of XML fragments - one for each element that matches the XPath provided. Since SQL Server doesn't have lists, it uses an internal (pseudo) table with a single column (containing the XML fragments)